# Spark flattening out dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, flatmap, spark-jobserver

getting started with spark I would like to know how to `flatmap` or `explode` a dataframe.

It was created using `df.groupBy("columName").count` and has the following structure if I collect it:

```
 [[Key1, count], [Key2, count2]]
```

But I would rather like to have something like

```
Map(bar -> 1, foo -> 1, awesome -> 1)
```

What is the right tool to achieve something like this? Flatmap, explode or something else?

Context: I want to use spark-jobserver. It only seems to provide meaningful results (e.g. a working json serialization) in case I supply the data in the latter forml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're calling `collect` or `collectAsList`on the DataFrame? That would return an `Array[Row]` / `List[Row]`.

If so - the easiest way to transform these into maps is to use the underlying RDD, map its recrods into key-value tuples and use `collectAsMap`:

```
def counted = df.groupBy("columName").count()
// obviously, replace "keyColumn" and "valueColumn" with your actual column names
def result = counted.rdd.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("keyColumn"), r.getAs[Long]("valueColumn"))).collectAsMap()
```

`result` has type `Map[String, Long]` as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately (even though the format is now the same as https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server-tests/src/spark.jobserver/WordCountExample.scala the WordCount example I still receive no JSON but rather my Map ...

Comment: "I still receive no JSON but rather my Map"... what do you mean? Where? Are you running your job via the server's REST API (e.g. using `curl`) or are you running the main in the job itself? If it's the latter, of course you'll get the map and not a JSON, when you call a method returning a `Map` it returns a `Map`, there's no magic.

Comment: the wordcount returns {
  "result": {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2,
    "see": 1,
    "c": 1
  }
I get 
  "result": "Map(1364767200000 -> 1.9517414004122625E15, 1380578400000 -> 6.9480992806496976E16)" for my job