# spark-jobserver serialzation format

Tags: json, scala, serialization, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

getting started with spark-jobserver I learnt that data frames can be flattend like [Spark flattening out dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541565/spark-flattening-out-dataframes) but this still does not fulfill https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#job-result-serialization

If this is the result I get from spark

```
Array([1364767200000,1.9517414004122625E15], [1380578400000,6.9480992806496976E16])
```

**how could I map it to a fitting format? (useful serialization)**
How could I add additional fields?

Trying to play with an array like: `Array([1,2], [3,4])` only results in an error.

Currently I get the following serialization based on [Spark flattening out dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541565/spark-flattening-out-dataframes):

```
 "result": "Map(1364767200000 -> 1.9517414004122625E15, 1380578400000 -> 6.9480992806496976E16)"
```

which obviously is not "parsed" by the jobs-erver.

As far as I understand it the nested arrays (from `collect`) cannot be serialized properly. However, this map should be serializable. What is wrong?

## edit

Only if I return a properly typed list the Json encoding seems to work.

```
  case class Student(name: String, age: Int)
List(Student("Torcuato", 27), Student("Rosalinda", 34))
```

The result is: `"result": [["Torcuato", 27], ["Rosalinda", 34]]`. Already for

```
  val dataFrame: DataFrame = sql.createDataFrame(sql.sparkContext.parallelize(List(Student("Torcuato", 27), Student("Rosalinda", 34))))
    dataFrame.collect
```

I get `"result": ["[Torcuato,27]", "[Rosalinda,34]"]` which is some strange kind of Json.

As far as I understand the problem I would need to parse all of my result into a custom class. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that for now apparently only Maps of strings are supported thus, this [Convert DataFrame to RDD[Map] in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618461/convert-arrayspark-sql-row-to-map-in-scala/36618865#36618865) results in clean serialization.