# Convert Row to map in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a row from a data frame and I want to convert it to a Map[String, Any] that maps column names to the values in the row for that column.

Is there an easy way to do it?

I did it for string values like

```
def rowToMap(row:Row): Map[String, String] = {
row.schema.fieldNames.map(field => field -> row.getAs[String](field)).toMap
}

val myRowMap = rowToMap(myRow)
```

If the row contains other values, not specific ones like String then the code gets messier because the row does not have a a method `.get(field)`

Any ideas?

Comment: share input and expected output foramt

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `getValuesMap`:

```
val df = Seq((1, 2.0, "a")).toDF("A", "B", "C")    
val row = df.first
```

To get `Map[String, Any]`:

```
row.getValuesMap[Any](row.schema.fieldNames)
// res19: Map[String,Any] = Map(A -> 1, B -> 2.0, C -> a)
```

Or you can get `Map[String, AnyVal]` for this simple case since the values are not complex objects

```
row.getValuesMap[AnyVal](row.schema.fieldNames)
// res20: Map[String,AnyVal] = Map(A -> 1, B -> 2.0, C -> a)
```

*Note*: <sub>the returned value type of the `getValuesMap` can be labelled as any type, so you can not rely on it to figure out what data types you have but need to keep in mind what you have from the beginning instead.</sub>

Comment: This is only possible if the row has a schema. This is tha case because you use a DF. In case you just pass a row without a schema you can extract values to a  Seq and then zip it together with the field names to a map.

Comment: error: Unable to find encoder for type Map[String,Any]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `dataframe` to `rdd` and use simple `map` function and use `headernames` in the `MAP` formation inside `map` function and finally use `collect`

```
val fn = df.schema.fieldNames
val maps = df.rdd.map(row => fn.map(field => field -> row.getAs(field)).toMap).collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a data Frame with these columns:

`[time(TimeStampType), col1(DoubleType), col2(DoubleType)]`

You can do something like this:

```
val modifiedDf = df.map{row => 
    val doubleObject = row.getValuesMap(Seq("col1","col2"))
    val timeObject = Map("time" -> row.getAs[TimeStamp]("time"))
    val map = doubleObject ++ timeObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a row without structure information and the column header as an array.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize( Seq(Row("test1", "val1"), Row("test2", "val2"), Row("test3", "val3"), Row("test4", "val4")) )
rdd.collect.foreach(println)

val sparkFieldNames = Array("col1", "col2")

val mapRDD = rdd.map(
  r => sparkFieldNames.zip(r.toSeq).toMap
)

mapRDD.collect.foreach(println)
```